# MVC accessing static file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble trying to access a file within my MVC application.  I have the following view:

```
@using CIT.ViewModels
@using static CIT.Common.Constants
@model IEnumerable<ProjectVM>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       @{int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_@i">
                <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_@i">
                    <div class="row"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

which basically creates a list of panels based on a viewmodel.  I'd like to access the CIT.Common.Constants file but for some reason it makes the

```
@{int i = 0;}
```

line blow up.  I can access that file from the controller using the same using statement, just wondering if something has to be different on the view.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/437. `using static` is not supported

Comment: for static class file no need to use `@using`, just call `@Constants.RoomTemperature` in view

Comment: Thank you pandian, that was it.